# How to allow the user to select both files and folders in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

```
def browse_file(self):
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*")])
    if file_path:
        self.localPath.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.localPath.insert(tk.END, file_path)
```

The function above allows users to select the file from the dialog box, but i wanted to allow the user to select either folder or file.

I want a method that can allow a user to select either file or folder when the function is called

Comment: `tkinter` does not provide such function and you need to create one yourself.

Comment: Is there any alternatives availabe why because I created a dialog box with push, pull features from the adb shell. for selecting the system/local path I need a feature that should work for selecting either file or directories. for pushing into adb shell user should have a option to browse either file or folder and when it comes to pull from adb shell definitely a directory need to be selected

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the input is `filename` or `directory`. Here is the sample code:

```
def browse_file_or_folder():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*")])
    if not file_path:
        folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
        if folder_path:
            # Handle the selected folder path
            print("Selected folder:", folder_path)
    else:
        # Handle the selected file path
        print("Selected file:", file_path)
        self.localPath.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.localPath.insert(tk.END, file_path)
```